# Relation between Twitter replies

Tags: api, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

I have a big problem with the Twitter API. Currently Twitter doesn't support fetching Tweets with their associated replies.

I would like to grap the mentions of the timeline and associate them with their replies.

Until this step everything is fine. Now my problem.
I would like to add also the children replies of a reply to get a full relation between the mention and the replies.

Currently I fetch the timeline and split the results into mentions and replies.

```
public void fetchTwitterTimeline(long sinceId) {
 try {
   Paging timelinePaging = new Paging();

   if (sinceId > 0) {
     timelinePaging.setSinceId(sinceId);
   }
   LOG.debug("Fetching Twitter Timeline");
   ResponseList<Status> statusResponseList = twitterClient.getMentionsTimeline(timelinePaging);
   assignTwitterStatusResponse(statusResponseList);
 } catch(TwitterException e){
   e.getStackTrace();
   System.out.println(e);
   LOG.error("Could not fetch Twitter Timeline: {}", e);
  }
}

private void assignTwitterStatusResponse(ResponseList<Status> statusResponseList) {
 for (Status status : statusResponseList) {
   if (status.isRetweet()) {
     continue;
   }

   if (status.getInReplyToStatusId() > 0) {
     replies.add(status);
   } else {
     mentions.add(status);
   }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks a lot for your response.
Now I have a good solution also for those who has the same problems with it.

```
public List<Status> fetchTwitterThread(long tweetId) throws TwitterException {
   Paging timelinePaging = new Paging();
   timelinePaging.setSinceId(tweetId);

   ResponseList<Status> statusResponseList = twitterClient.getMentionsTimeline(timelinePaging);
   statusResponseList.addAll(twitterClient.getHomeTimeline(timelinePaging));

   List<Status> thread = new ArrayList<>();
   thread.add(getStatusById(tweetId)); // Add root status

   fetchTwitterThread(tweetId, statusResponseList, thread);

   return thread;
}

private void fetchTwitterThread(long parentId, ResponseList<Status> statusResponseList, List<Status> thread) {
  for (Status status : statusResponseList) {
    if (status.getInReplyToStatusId() == parentId) {
      thread.add(status);
      fetchTwitterThread(status.getId(), statusResponseList, thread);
    }
  }
}
```

I have two methods. This will be needed if you want to save some API calls.
In the first step I fetch the mentionsTimeline and the hometimeline since the requested id. This is necessary for you own tweets and replies.

After that I've implemented a second method as a recursion. I iterate through the responseList and if one status (inReplyToStatusId) matches with the parentId, I add them to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API call to get the replies to the tweets.

It is `conversation/show/:ID` - so to get all the replies to Tweet ID 123 you'd call `conversation/show/123`

The only problem is that this API is restricted to Twitter's official API keys.

Comment: I couldn't use this for my application. Is there another possibility to get at least all replies for the tweet. For my purpose it's unnecessary to get the whole relation of each reply. It's enough to get a chronological List of all Replies.

Comment: You can use search for this. For example perform a search for "@fabian" to get everyone who has replied to you. Then filter by `reply_id`

Comment: So thank you for your help. I posted a good one solution for this problem. Maybe in the future Twitter will improve their API.